# code does't showing any output terminating while execution time

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, struct, insert

this is the code for inserting an element in an array,does not showing any output but terminatting forcefully while execution.

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<stdlib.h>

struct array
 {
int a[10];
int size;
int length;
};

void display(struct array arr)
{
int i;
printf("\nthe elemenets are\n");
for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
{
    printf("%d ",arr.a[i]);
}
}

void insert(struct array *arr,int index,int value)
{
int i;

if(index>=0&&index<=arr->length)
{
    for(i=arr->length;i>index;i++)
        arr->a[i]=arr->a[i-1];
    arr->a[index]=value;
    arr->length++;
}
}

 int main()
 {
 struct array arr1={{1,2,3,4,5},10,5};
 insert(&arr1,2,45);
 display(arr1);
 return 0;
 }
```

i am thinking there could be a problem in the display function but unable to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This loop is invalid

```
if(index>=0&&index<=arr->length)
{
    for(i=arr->length;i>index;i++)
        arr->a[i]=arr->a[i-1];
    arr->a[index]=value;
    arr->length++;
}
```

because at least the variable i is incremented instead of be decremented. And the condition in the if statement

```
if(index>=0&&index<=arr->length)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

is invalid.

I think you mean the following

```
if ( index>=0 && index < arr->length )
{
    for ( i = arr->length; i-1 >index; i-- )
        arr->a[i-1] = arr->a[i-2];

    arr->a[index] = value;
    arr->length++;
}
```